# Not able to connect to database in heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am using Heroku PostgreSQL add-on till yesterday it was working as expected for today I checked got below issue:

```
{
"name": "error",
"length": 110,
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "42P01",
"position": "13",
"file": "parse_relation.c",
"line": "1173",
"routine": "parserOpenTable"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error `42P01` in Postgres, generally shows up because of one the following reason.

1. **Improper Database setup**: You might have forgot to give the privilege to access to the database/table to the user with which you are trying to access the DB.
2. **Common Mistake of Unquoted Identifiers**: Some people, create tables with mixed-case letters. Usually, the unquoted identifiers are folded into lowercase. So, when the customer queries the table name with the mixed case it shows 42P01 error. The happens as the PostgreSQL has saved the table name in lower case. To resolve this error, our Support Engineers give mixed case table name in quotes. Also, we highly recommend to NOT use quotes in database names. Thus it would make PostgreSQL behave non-case sensitive.
3. **Database query on a non-public schema**: Similarly, the PostgreSQL 42P01 error occurs when a user queries a non-public schema.

You may go ahead and see if in some query there's a typo in Table Name, or some similar access issue.

source: https://bobcares.com/blog/postgresql-error-42p01/

Comment: I have added one question  related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547466/unable-to-connect-to-heroku-postgresql-database-locally-it-suddenly-stopped-work