# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL through nodejs database locally it suddenly stopped working on mac

Tags: node.js, postgresql, macos, heroku

I am able to connect to Heroku PostgreSQL after deploying in Heroku, but not Unable to connect to Heroku PostgreSQL from locally. It was working till yesterday. Using mac machine.

env.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
export default {
database_url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
test_database_url: process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
secret: process.env.SECRET,
port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
twoFactorAPIKey: process.env.TWOFACTOR_API_KEY
}
```

pool.js

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import env from '../../../env';
const databaseConfig = { connectionString: env.database_url };
const pool = new Pool(databaseConfig);
export default pool;
```

When is try with postman getting below screen:

[image]

note* I had installed NVM  yesterday  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating

Comment: Please add some more information, any error logs or messages we can work with.

Comment: Right now in am testing on postman there is only one message sending request apart from this there is no message and log.

Comment: Resolved this issue by updating pg "pg": "^8.3.2", and node v14.8.0

Comment: Please post that [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by updating pg "pg": "^8.3.2", and node v14.8.0